# Extra argument "result block" in ALAssetsLibrary.assetForURL

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, swift2

I'm trying to translate this code from obj-c to swift 2.1:

```
[[ALAssetsLibrary new] assetForURL:info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    // do something
  } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // do something else
  }];
```

And I get this error:

[image]

Anyone knows whats the issue here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix that, but if possible please migrate to:

```
import Photos
PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers(<#T##identifiers: [String]##[String]#>, options: <#T##PHFetchOptions?#>)
```

For reference it should look like this in swift, if you cannot migrate away from deprecated ALAssetsLibrary to Photos framework.

```
    ALAssetsLibrary().assetForURL(NSURL(string: ""), resultBlock: { (asset: ALAsset!) -> Void in
        //do something
        }) { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! Can't migrate to PHAsset, still supporting iOS 7.